# How do I accept an answer in this new layout?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I can't seem to figure out how to accept an answer in this new layout.  I also can't see the arrows for upvoting or downvoting.  Is it me, or is it the layout?

Comment: Are you using IE? There were [other problems](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/407/hills-bike-etc-disappear-in-ie-8) with CSS in IE.

Comment: you should be able to see the voting arrows and answer checkmark. Make sure you do a hard refresh. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: @thajigisup - Has Jin's suggestion taken care of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There should be triangles with arrows for voting and a square with a checkmark next to answers, like in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpEPg.jpg

If you could provide a screenshot and browser version info, that might help with debugging.